# Excel vba For Each & For loop

Tags: vba, excel

```
lastColumn_Of_PO_line_Big_Table = Sheets("PO_line_Big_Table").UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
a = Dict_Metadata.Keys
For Each b In a
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr_PO_line_Big_Table)
        If Arr_PO_line_Big_Table(i, 1) = b Then
            With Worksheets("PO_line_Big_Table")
                nextRow = Sheets("Final_Result").Cells(Sheets("Final_Result").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
                '.Cells(nextRow, "A") = strKey
                '.Cells(i + 1, lastColumn_Of_PO_line_Big_Table) = "YES"
                Union(.Cells(i + 1, "E"), .Cells(i + 1, "K"), .Cells(i + 1, "L"), .Cells(i + 1, "M")).Copy
                Sheets("Final_Result").Range("B" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Could someone please tell me why it doesn't paste the value in sheet `"PO_line_Big_Table"` to sheet `Final_Result`, thank you in advanced!!

Comment: What error are you getting? Just using your `Union(.Cells... .Copy` and the `PasteSpecial` lines, the code seems to copy just fine.

Comment: There's no error message, the problem is only one row is showed in the sheet `Final_Result` in the end, so I think probably I misused the for syntax

Comment: You need to increment your `nextRow` variable after you use it: `nextRow = nextRow + 1`

Comment: Sorry, I tried and I don't think thats the problem, Cause I calculate nextrow every loop.

Comment: It's because your `nextRow` is based on Column A but you're placing your value in Column B. Change to `nextRow = ... .Rows.Count, 2)...`

Comment: Try `Debug.Print nextRow` inside the loop to see what's being calculated. Your loop is either running only once, or `nextRow` is calculated to the same row every time.